# windowActionBar=false unnecessary to hide action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

Usually the following 2 attributes are added to a theme in order to remove the action bar:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

However, I noticed that it also works when I remove the `windowActionBar` attribute completely. Is this attribute obsolete?